# Viewing distributions as "generalized functions"

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

A distribution is defined to be element of the dual space of $C_0^\infty$. Since a distribution is thus a linear functional, I would think that a distribution is itself a function but this is not the case as can be seen by the Dirac-$\delta$ function. I am thus a little unclear on what a distribution is exactly if it's somehow more than a linear functional. What do we exactly mean by saying they are "generalized functions", why not just view them as linear functionals?

Comment: Who says it’s ’more’ than a linear functional on $C_c^{\infty}$? ‘Generalized functions’ is just a name. It is ‘generalized’ in the sense that there are ‘more of them’ (i.e there is an injective, non-surjective linear embedding of $C^{\infty}_c$ or even $L^1$ into the dual $(C^{\infty}_c)’$ via integration).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I suppose what I was curious about was why the "generalized" part of the name exists, or at least what was the motivation behind that. So the issue is that there are linear functions on $C_c^\infty$ than $C_c^\infty$, and that is why we cannot achieve a surjection?

Comment: yes, the generalizedness is referring to non-surjectivity, which is seen from examples like the Dirac delta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We *do* view distributions as mappings $C_0^\infty \to \mathbb{R}$. As peek-a-boo notes, that's really all there is to say.

---

Half-explanation of why we think of distributions as "generalized functions":

Some distributions can be constructed from, say,
continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$: specifically, such an $f$ can be used to construct a distribution $D_f : C_0^\infty \to \mathbb{R}$ via $D_f(\psi) := \int f \psi$. So in some sense, every nice function $f$ has a corresponding distribution $D_f$.

However, there are distributions $D$ that cannot be written in this way (i.e. there exists no $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $D(\psi) = \int g \psi$ for all $\psi$). So the collection of distributions contains "more" than nice functions, so it is more "general."

Comment: So the "generalized" part of the title is simply to account for *all* linear functionals on $C_0^\infty$, including those that cannot be written in terms of an integral?

Comment: Also, like functions, distribution have a local (although not point-wise) behavior or identity; we can say that two distributions are equal on some open set. They are also differentiable. Therefore we often abuse notation and treat them almost as functions.